# How to do periodic polling/query to database in every 5 sec in background in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cron

I have a ruby on rails application which sends push notifications based on new records created in database in every 5 seconds. Is there any way apart from CRON jobs to do polling/query in DB to check for new records.

My current code implementation is running CRON evey minute which sleeps for 5 seconds, but this approach taking huge memory consumption.

```
schedule.rb #whenever gem file

 every 1.minute do
  runner "DailyNotificationChecker.send_notifications"
end
```

*
    ### below code calls method process_notes every 5 sec

```
    def self.send_notifications
        expiry_time = Time.now + 57
        while (Time.now < expiry_time)
            if RUN_SCHEDULER == "true" || RUN_SCHEDULER == true
              process_notes  #calls method mentioned below
            end
          sleep 5 #seconds
        end
      end


 ### below code check for new records and sends notification


    def self.process_notes
      notes = nil
      time = Benchmark.measure do
        Note.uncached do
          notes = Note.where("(created_at > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 minute)) AND `notes`.`processed` = 0")
          if notes.present?
            note_ids = notes.collect{|x| x.id}
            RealtimeNotifier.new.delay.perform(note_ids,NOTE_CREATED,TEMP_USER_NOTE)
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

This code snippet is working but not an optimised solution. Is there a better way to achieve this.

Comment: try https://github.com/zendesk/ruby-kafka

Comment: Or perhaps https://github.com/Ebbe/arask would work better. Add this line in Arask configuration: `arask.create script: 'DailyNotificationChecker.send_notifications', interval: 5.seconds`. This should make Rails automatically run the task every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL allows you to setup a trigger that calls a user defined function (written in C or C++), other databases might have a similar functionality. From there you can replace the current running process with a bash script in which you place the command(s) to run. I can't give you an example, since I never needed this. But this might point you in the right direction.

Have a look at the following pages:

- [MySQL Adding a New User-Defined Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-udf.html)
- [man 3 exec](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) (you might need [man 2 fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to first split of a new process here is an [example](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/icsrts/Tutorials/fork_exec/))
- [How to Create and Use Bash Scripts](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-create-and-use-bash-scripts/) (trigger rake command here)

Applying this solution would change your poll based solution into a push based solution.

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try this and post my findings here.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a ruby on rails application which sends push notifications based on new records created in database in every 5 seconds.

So you currently have a job/process that sits in memory and polls database, then does something about new records. How about inverting the workflow? Some other part of your code creates those records, yes? Also make that part put a new `RealtimeNotifier` job in the queue. Cut out the middleman<sup>*</sup>, so to say.

---

<sub>* yes, the code is now more coupled, but also easier to reason about.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for taking time @sergio, I understand your explanation but the scenario is that data comes in the database from back door. It does not gets created from rails app and that's why I cannot use a callback or couple the code there.

Comment: @Prem: I see. Well, let's hope this answer will help another visitor.